# Sampler gives High CPU load on socket.receive(packet)

Tags: java, udp

I'm, trying to minimize the footprint of a Java program.
The JVisualVM Sampler tells me that the socket.receive() takes a lot of CPU time, even if no data is coming in.
The socket is blocking and not connected to any other machine.
Is this just a problem of the sampler or a problem of the JVM or my Code?

```
// constructor
if (this.isRunning && !this.socket.isClosed())
        return;
    this.socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    this.isRunning = true;
    super.start();
...
// receive loop
while (this.isRunning && !thread.isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];

        // receive request
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        this.socket.receive(packet);
        if (isRunning) {
            tokenize(packet, true);
        }
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        LOG.warn("Socket closed from outside");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think that is a problem, but rather how sockets were defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receive( ) is a blocking operation so the thread that executes it, will be blocked.
JVisualVM is saying that the thread is spending much time there (which is normal as nothing will be done until a new connection arrives).
You can also check the thread monitor to see the % time that the thread is blocked (i.e. in a I/O operation).

Ps. You might want to create worker threads in order to process the received packets. Otherwise your service will be able to handle just one request at a time.